# Local Storage returns [object HTML_InputElement] instead of value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to make a Notes App. When I write the text and title of the note on one page (new note.html) and display it on the main page (index.html) by local storage, the main page doesn't seem to detect the local storage text to display it, so these errors appear: [object HTMLInputElement] and [object HTMLTextAreaElement].

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEBsP.png)

When nothing is typed inside the fields on "new note.html", the following text displays on the main page: "There aren't any notes", but if anything is typed in the title and write field, the text typed is supposed to display at the main page (index.html), using the savetitle() and savewrite() functions when a button styled by a green arrow is clicked, but [object HTMLInputElement] and [object HTMLTextAreaElement] displays instead.

## code of the "new note.html" page:

```
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <a onclick="savetitle(), savewrite()" class="back" href="./index.html">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left fa-lg" style="color: #00e927;"></i></a>
        <input class="title" id="title" type="text" spellcheck="false" maxlength="15" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <textarea class="write" id="write" rows="30" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>
<script>
    function savetitle() {
        var title = document.getElementById("title");

        if (title !== "") {
            localStorage.setItem("title", title)
        }
    }
    function savewrite() {
        var write = document.getElementById("write");

        if (write !== "") {
            localStorage.setItem("write", write);
        }
    }
```

## code of the "index.html" page:

```
<body>
      <div class="notes"><h1>Notes</h1></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div id="titled"></div>
      <div id="written"></div>
      <a class="new" href="./new note.html">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square fa-x18" style="color: #00e927;"></i></a>
<script>
  var titled = localStorage.getItem("title");

  if (titled) {
    document.getElementById("titled").textContent = titled;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("titled").textContent = "There isn't any notes"
  } 

  var written = localStorage.getItem("write");

  if (written) {
    document.getElementById("written").textContent = written;
  }
```

Comment: You're trying to save the element itself to the storage, and since the element isn't a string it's converted into a string describing the object, like `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`. You should save the element's value instead, e.g. `localStorage.setItem("title", title.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple and easy

The problem was that your are using `document.getElementById("title")` without the `.value` at the end like this : `document.getElementById("title").value`

Here is the complete newNote.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>New Note</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <input class="title" id="title" type="text" spellcheck="false" maxlength="15" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <textarea class="write" id="write" rows="`0" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="saveCompleteNote()">Save Complete Note</button>
    <script>

        function saveCompleteNote() {
            savetitle();
            savewrite();
        }

        function savetitle() {
            var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
            console.log(title);

            if (title !== "") {
                localStorage.setItem("title", title)
            }
        }
        function savewrite() {
            var write = document.getElementById("write").value;
            console.log(write)

            if (write !== "") {
                localStorage.setItem("write", write);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```